# use values in a column as a parameters

Tags: excel, vba, loops, parameters

I need to read the values from a column and pass the single values as a parameter for a function.
here's my code:

```
Sub Function3()
Dim FileFull As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Worksheets("Foglio3").Activate
FileFull = Dir(Range("A1").Value)

Do While FileFull <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileFull)
    Delete_Sheet wb
    InsertCol wb
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

The other functions will use the value stored on the FileFull variable.
the values on the Foglio3 are:

```
C:\scriptest\FolderA\2021\3-Corrs\fileA_2021.xlsm
C:\scriptest\FolderB\2021\3-Corrs\fileB_2021.xlsm
C:\scriptest\FolderC\2021\3-Corrs\fileC_2021.xlsm
C:\scriptest\FolderD\2021\3-Corrs\fileD_2021.xlsm
C:\scriptest\FolderE\2021\3-Corrs\fileE_2021.xlsm
```

I have 2 problems. how can I loop into the range of Foglio3 cells from A1 to A300 and use the values as a parameter to the other functions?
thanks!

Comment: If your other functions have `wb` as a parameter then `FileFull` will be [wb.FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.fullname)

Comment: To loop through a range and pass the values -> `For Each Cell in MyRange.Cells: MyFunction(Cell.Value): Next` where Cell is defined `Dim Cell As Range`. For A1 to A300 -> `Set MyRange = Range("A1:A300")` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

### Process Multiple Workbooks

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessMultipleWorkbooks()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Process Multiple Workbooks"
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Foglio3")
    ' Either...
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1:A300")
    ' ... or to make it dynamic:
    'Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    'Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1", slCell)
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        dFilePath = CStr(sCell.Value)
        If Len(Dir(dFilePath)) > 0 Then ' destination file path exists
            On Error Resume Next
            Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dFilePath)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not dwb Is Nothing Then ' file opened
                ' Debug.Print dwb.Name
                Delete_Sheet dwb
                InsertCol dwb
                dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
            'Else ' file not opened
            End If
        'Else ' destination file path doesn't exist
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation, ProcTitle

End Sub
```